# Migrate one question, Close another

Tags: discussion, migration, moderation, closing-questions

This question:

- [Why is "||" the symbol for or?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15056896/)

was closed for being Off-topic on StackOverflow.  I recommend that it be migrated to here, where it would be decidedly more topical.

Then, I recommend that this question be closed as a duplicate:

- [Why is a vertical bar used as the OR operator in so many programming languages?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/317905/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question on Stack Overflow was asked over 4 years ago. It cannot be migrated due to its age.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Thomas Owens said, there is another thought to consider, which is [my close vote](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/317905/why-is-a-vertical-bar-used-as-the-or-operator-in-so-many-programming-languages#comment739921_317905) on the question asked here:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about
>   the systems development life cycle.

The core question is one of the history of programming language design. While history is interesting, it does not fit into the systems development life cycle. It does not address a problem to be solved anywhere between requirements gathering and deploying a finished system.

That being said, [sometimes questions about programming history do end up staying open](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7188/), or get a historical lock.